# Staying in while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I don't know why, but my program keeps exiting while loop ( the one inside "if" statement)

the input file contains "abc abb ca" and this should put "abc" and "abb" into one (stack_arr[0]) stack and "ca" into different one ( stack_arr[2])

```
   fin.get(ch);
   while (fin)
    {
        if((int)ch>=97 && (int)ch<=122)
        {
            x=(int)ch-97;

            while(fin && (int)ch>=97 && (int)ch<=122)
           {
               stack_arr[x].push(ch);
               fin.get(ch);
           }
        }

        fin.get(ch);
    }
```

but it only puts all the 'a' in one stack, all the 'b' in another and so on... i found out that in inner while loop it enters, does one cycle, but does not stay. I cannot understand why is it so.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Also please stop use character codes.  If you want to compare against single characters do that like `if(ch == 'a')...`.  It is a lot easier to understand and will make the code more portable as `97` is not required to be the character you think it is.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but none of those casts is needed.

Comment: I am pushing into the stack. There is an array of stacks (one for every small case letter from 'a' to 'z') `stack stack_arr [26];` and x just means that is x-the stack that I push in. That's why I also use ASCII to int - to make sure that I push word with a starting character into the appropriate stack.

Comment: Are you trying to make an array of stacks that have the words from the file and each stack holds words starting with the same letter(one stack for each letter of the alphabet)?

Comment: What is a `true` value for `fin`? what is a `false` value? What would be wrong if second `while` looked like this: `while( (int)ch>=97 && (int)ch<=122)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I am. Next I am outputing it on another file all sorted in alphabetical order ( just by first letter, not all letters).

Comment: @marlan basicly fin is just file that I am reading 
`fstream fin;
fin.open ("example.txt", ios::in);` 

`fin` is `true` if `ch` is not at the end of file. `false` - if it is end of file. 
I thought that if in inner while loop `fin.get(ch)` is end of file that it will still do one more `fin.get(ch)` whitch will come after end of file causing errors.

Comment: Are you sure it is the fstream object you should test, not the eof bit? otherwise your logic looks (to me) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your current approach you could make use of the STL (after all, you *are* programming in C++) to create a more sparse structure containing the different strings:

```
std::ifstream fin("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);
std::map<char, std::vector<std::string>> stack;
std::string token;
while (getline(fin, token, ' ')) {
    if (!stack.count(token[0])) {
        stack[token[0]] = {};
    }
    stack[token[0]].push_back(token);
}
fin.close();

// Print the contents
for (auto& e : stack) {
    std::cout << "key = " << e.first << "\n";
    for (auto& s : e.second) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

If I run this with the following in test.txt:

> abc abb ca
>   ccb kw

I get the following output:

> key = a
>   abc
>   abb
>   key = c
>   ca
>   ccb
>   key = k
>   kw

Some people might frown at the use of `std::map`, and if performance is a major concern then perhaps you should be looking at other classes. I just picked a simple implementation.

Comment: Thanks, It would make a lot of sense, and I would do it in real life application, but this is an assignment where I must create my own data structures. So that excludes STL and string and vectors and... any other pre-made data structures.

Comment: `auto fin = std::ifstream("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);` Is that even valid? I thought this form required an accessible copy constructor. Is movability sufficient? And why even do a move? Just declare the object normally... in the same way that you declare your other objects...

Comment: @MagicKriss I really wished they taught C++ the other way around.  First learn about the data structures and algorithms and how you can use them and then go into learning how they work under the hood.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess I've been writing to much Java lately. The code compiles fine with GCC 5.2.0 and `-std=c++14` though.

Comment: @Michael: Java has `auto` now? Wow!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it initializes `fin` from an rvalue, so doesn't require a copy constructor, a move constructor is OK (and should be elided, of course). It's still silly though, `std::ifstream fin("test.txt");` is much simpler. There's no need to say you want the `in` mode on an ifstream ... it would be stupid if ifstreams didn't default to reading input.